# fontSize are not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uifont

I have created an application in which I have added  text into a video through `UITextView. It's displaying properly but the problem is that I have set the text font size like this:

```
[textView  setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:35]];
```

and it works for the font sizes 18,20 but it isn't working properly for large font sizes like 30 , 35, etc.

Code for creating textview programmatically:

```
UITextView *textView =[[UITextView alloc] init];
textView.text = @"text here";
[textView  setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:35]];
[textView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];
[textView setTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
textView.frame=CGRectMake(35,35,500,500);
textView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
[textView setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

Comment: Is the text cropping if you set a larger size? Then you might need to increase height of the textview to accommodate your text.

Comment: What happen when you modifie the text size? Is not see?

Comment: it's displaying but text is cropping.

Comment: Can you suggest me some lines of code for setting the height of the text view @NSNoob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code,

```
    UITextView *textView =[[UITextView alloc] init];
    textView.text = @"text here";
    [textView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:90]];
    textView.delegate = self;
    [textView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];
    [textView setTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
    textView.frame=CGRectMake(20,35,self.view.frame.size.width-40,200);
    [textView setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
    textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self.view addSubview:textView];
```

You set the frame size wrong, In Iphone width size is 360 to 414 only, but you give 500, the above working for me, see the output,

[image]

hope its helpful

Comment: Thanks a lot. it's really working for me as i expect

Comment: can you tell me how to set the orientation of the text in textview without using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation? @lyyappan Ravi

Comment: CGAffineTransformMakeRotation is not important, if you set the Frame correctly automatically en large the textview text orientation portrait or landscape.

Comment: No actually i want to rotate it in any dimensions like up, bottom, left , right etc.

Comment: if you need CGAffineTransformMakeRotation, ok use it rotations working fine

Answer (score 1):

Use this Code,

```
[textView setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
```

or

```
[textView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
```

And also set the delegate in `UITextview`

```
textView.delegate=self;
```

give the delegate in top of the class, example

```
@interface ViewController1 : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
```

hope its helpful

Comment: This is also working for small sizes not for the large sizes

Comment: i think your textview frame size is small

Comment: if you set the delegate in UITextView

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try this code

```
[textView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:35]];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not working as i expect.